# Total de valores em django template

Tags: python, django, django-templates

Estou desenvolvendo um forum que na pagina index eu preciso mostrar o assunto, quantos tópicos tem esse assunto e quantos post, eu até consigo voltar quantidade de tópicos, mas só mostra o tópico com o id do assunto 1, por exemplo se tiver o assunto 2 vai voltar a quantidade do assunto 1.

essa é a minha views

```
def index(request):

    topico = Topico.objects.all()
    total = len(topico)

    assunto_jogo = Assunto.objects.filter(id_categoria=1)
    context = {
        'assunto': assunto_jogo,
        'topicos': topico,
        'total': total
    }
    return render(request, "index.html", context)
```

e esse o trecho do template onde será mostrado a quantidade

```
{% for assuntos in assunto %}
                          <tbody>

                            <tr>
                                <td class="text-center" style="width: 40px;"><i class="fa fa-globe fa-2x text-muted"></i></td>
                                <td>
                                    <h5>
                                        <a href="topic.html">{{ assuntos }}</a>
                                        <small class="d-block">
                                            {{ assuntos.descricao }}
                                        </small>
                                    </h5>
                                </td>

                                <td class="text-center hidden-xs hidden-sm">
                                        {% if topicos.id_assunto == 1: %}
                                        {{ total }}
                                        {% endif %}
                                </td>
                                <td class="text-center hidden-xs hidden-sm">
                                    1342
                                </td>
                                <td class="hidden-xs hidden-sm">por
                                    <b>Game Master</b>
                                    <br>
                                    <small><i>1 nov 2017, 14:30</i></small>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                         </tbody>
                        {% endfor %}
```

e os models

```
class Topico(models.Model):

    titulo = models.CharField('Título', max_length=100)
    mensagem = models.TextField('Mensagem')
    data_criacao = models.DateTimeField('data de criação', auto_now_add=True, blank=True, null=True)
    avatar = models.ImageField(upload_to='core/images', verbose_name='Imagem', blank=True, null=True)
    id_usuario = models.ForeignKey(Adm)
    id_assunto = models.ForeignKey(Assunto)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.titulo

class Post(models.Model):

    mensagem = models.TextField('Mensagem')
    avatar = models.ImageField(upload_to='core/images', verbose_name='Imagem', blank=True, null=True)
    data_criacao = models.DateTimeField('data de criação', auto_now_add=True)
    id_usuario = models.ForeignKey(Adm)
    id_topico = models.ForeignKey(Topico)
    id_assunto = models.ForeignKey(Assunto)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.mensagem
```

como pode ser feito isso?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para carregar os assuntos, tópicos ou posts que o usuário quer ler, você deve passar um parâmetro para que a *view* filtre os itens selecionados.

**Exemplo da lógica:**

Utilizando a template tag [urls](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/templates/builtins/#url) você pode linkar para o respectivo conteúdo clicado:

```
{% for assunto in assuntos %}
    <a href="{% url 'topico' assunto.topico.id %}">
{% endfor %}
```

Neste caso ele estaria pegando a URL referente a topico conforme definido na `urls.py` e gerando o link. Informações na [documentação](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/urls/#url-dispatcher).

Na sua **views.py** você estaria recebendo o ID do tópico, assunto ou post, e filtrando pelo `Assunto.objects.filter(id=assunto_id)`. Esse `assunto_id` estará sendo recebido pelo parâmetro da sua *view*.

```
def index(request, assunto_id):
    ...
```

O problema que você está enfrentando só poderá ser resolvido lendo a documentação que mostra passo a passo como desenvolver o código responsável por carregar os dados através de parâmetros passados pela URL. Todo esse processo envolverá a **view.py**, **urls.py** e seu **template.html**.